# connected subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to **python** and having some subprocess related doubt. I want to go to any directory and do something on that location. so i tried like this:

```
q1 = subprocess.Popen('cd ~/Desktop/my_folder', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out1, err) = q1.communicate()
```

Now when I did

```
q2 = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdin=q1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out2, err) = q2.communicate()
```

i saw that the ls command has been performed where I was before, so it means that q1 process is killed, I just want to know how to perform something in q1 process.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` is a bit special. Every process has its own current working directory. Thus when you create a subprocess for `cd ~/Desktop/my_folder`, the current directory is only changed for that particular subprocess (which exits right after changing its directory).

The parent process as well as any further subprocesses are unaffected.

The easiest way to change the directory is by using [`os.chdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Answer (score 0):

You can do os related operations by [Shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) library.